# HSTS header not being added correctly

Tags: security, ssl

I've added the following code to my child theme's `functions.php` in order to add a HSTS header to my website:

```
function tg_enable_strict_transport_security_hsts_header_wordpress() {
    header( 'Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload' );
}
add_action( 'send_headers', 'tg_enable_strict_transport_security_hsts_header_wordpress' );
```

However, this doesn't seem to work. When I check the headers in Chrome, the HSTS header is listed in the Network tab in the Developer tools, but it's not listed in Edge. https://httpstatus.io/ also doesn't list the HSTS header. Does anyone know why the header isn't (properly) added and how could this be fixed? 
 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: When and where are you adding the action? Have you cleared _all_ caches you have on your site including CDN level and browser caches?

Comment: @TomJNowell The action is added at the end of my child theme's `functions.php` file. Yes, I've cleared all caches.